# How is Pauli's exclusion principle valid for electrons of two hydrogen atoms in ground state, having same spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-states

Suppose we have two hydrogen atoms in the ground state with spin of both electrons pointing upwards. Then the two electrons are in the same state. This should be against the exclusion principle.
Now suppose we have 1 mole of hydrogen atoms in a chamber. Certainly, most of them will be in the ground state (at sufficiently low temperature), and among any three of those in the ground state, at least two will have spin in the same directions, hence the two electrons are in the same state. How is the exclusion principle valid for those two electrons?

My doubt is mostly about which parameters determine a "state". Suppose two different hydrogen atoms having the same quantum numbers are in different points in space. Are the two electrons in the same state?

Comment: I have edited the question as it was being marked "too broad".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quantum state includes the information about a particle's position. Two particles with the same quantum numbers at different locations are in different states, so are allowed by the exclusion principle.

Comment: Since there is the uncertainty principle, can we really ever say that the two particles are in the same position?

Comment: No, but then you can't say they have the same momentum either. The point is that the quantum state includes all th information about the particle and it must all be the same to be disallowed by the Pauli Exclusion Principle

Comment: Remember that the wavefunction for $n$ identical fermions isn't $n$ different functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ - it's a single function defined on the *configuration space* $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$, not on real space. The exclusion principle says that the *joint* probability (density) for two particles to both be at the exact position simultaneously is zero. However, *if* the wavefunction can be expressed as a Slater determinant of $n$ different single-particle wavefunctions (which is not always the case), then WLOG the single-particle states can be chosen to be orthogonal, but they are ...

Comment: ... allowed to overlap. Roughly speaking, you can have a nonzero probability of measuring particle $A$ at position $x$, and also a nonzero probability of measuring particle $B$ at position $x$, as long as the probability of simultaneously measuring particles $A$ and $B$ to *both* be at position $x$ is zero (neglecting spin, etc.). @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: @tparker Er wait a second. Statisticians will tell you the probability of any two continuous measurements being equal is zero. You need some kind of tolerance for non zero probability of equality. Given that has to do with numbers not physics what is the Pauli Exclusion Principle really telling us?

Comment: @candied_orange $p(x_1, x_2)$ isn't zero when $x_1 = x_2$ for an arbitrary probability density $p$.

Comment: @tpaker so the PEP only applies precisely at e.g., $x_1 = x_2$? but within measure theory probability densities are arbitrary at any particular point, such that your statement of the PEP is meaningless...

Comment: @candied_orange That's why I put "(density)" in parentheses in my comment above. Remember that the wavefunction gives you probability densities, not probabilities, and these can be either zero or nonzero.

Comment: @innisfree No, the PEP doesn't only apply exactly at $x_1 = x_2$. It says that $\lim \limits_{x_2 \to x_1} \psi(x_1, x_2) = 0$ for spinless fermions.

Comment: Hmm before you spoke in terms of probabilities, now wave functions. Would you say PEP says $\lim_{x_2\to x_1} p(x_1, x_2) =0$? I’m not sure that’s any more meaningful from a measure perspective of probability densities.

Comment: @innisfree You can look at $q(x):=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{P(X \in B_\varepsilon(x))}{V(B_\varepsilon(x))}$ where $V$ is the volume in the ambient measure and $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x$. This is the "true value" of the PDF wherever it exists. The points where $q$ exists are called Lebesgue points, and if the ambient measure is the Lebesgue measure then the set of all non-Lebesgue points has measure zero. PEP tells you about $q$, not just the probability density $p$ itself (which is not, strictly speaking, even well-defined).

Comment: @innisfree $p$ is just the absolute square of $\psi$, so it's equivalent to say that either goes to zero. The limit can be well-defined - you basically just take the usual definition of limit and replace every statement of the phrase "for all" with "for almost all" (in the measure-theory sense of "all except for a set of measure zero"). Remember that the elements of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are not functions but equivalence classes of functions. The limit above can be equivalently interpreted to mean "there exists a representative of the equivalence class $\psi$ such ...

Comment: ...  that this limit statement applies for that representative function."

Comment: @tparker then would this be fair to say: $\lim \limits_{x_2 \to x_1} \psi(x_1, x_2)$ < $\lim \limits_{x_2 \to x_1+1} \psi(x_1, x_2)$? If that's true then PEP really is saying something about being in the same place rather then simply the unlikelyhood of being at any specific place.

Comment: @candied_orange I'm afraid I don't understand your question. As you say, the uncertainty principle does forbid pairs of electrons from being at the same place, but it doesn't forbid any individual electron from being at any particular absolute location (disregarding any other electrons).

Comment: @tparker I'm testing (or attempting to test) whether your limit shows anything significant in comparison to an equally specific location some arbitrary distance away. In other words, are we getting zero because of the other particle or because it's really unlikely to be at any specific place? I get that PEP forbids being in the same place. But this limit doesn't yet reassure me that it forbids that any more strongly than being in any particular specific place.

Comment: @candied_orange Oh, I see your question. Yes, the PEP means that it's "even more unlikely" than the "usual" zero probability of being in any particular place. More precisely, the probability of the second electron being within an infinitesimal volume of the first electron is so tiny that it's *still* zero even *after* you divide by the infinitesimal volume. It's like it's "doubly" infinitesimal, while the usual probability of being in a generic place is only "singly" infinitesimal.

Comment: tparker @ian thanks for your explanations - very clear

Answer (score 4):

1. You can't create two electrons with the same momentum, because you can't create even a single electron with a particular, exact momentum. You can create an electron whose spatial wavefunction contains an arbitrarily narrow distribution of momenta, but then the distribution over spatial locations will be very broad. Independent of this, if they are localized in different regions of space, then their spatial states are different.
2. Assuming the electrons in different H atoms are bound to distinct nucleii, their states will be distinct because of this. In principle, though, if we ignore the nucleii and just put a lot of electrons in a box at low T, we can get a degenerate Fermi gas in which the exclusion principle does matter. The situation is more complicated when nucleii are involved.
3. The spatial state of any particle is part of its state with regard to the exclusion principle, so no, two electrons in two different atoms are never in the same state. Often we focus on their atomic (orbital+spin) states, and people often just call these the "states," but with regard to the Pauli exclusion principle, the spatial state definitely also matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you can say they are in different parts of the Universe, then that means you *do* have position information, even if only a small amount, which means that there is also less momentum information, even if such may be quite ample. It also means that they thus cannot be attributed the same quantum state. Hence, Pauli does not forbid it.

Two electrons with perfect momentum information would, indeed, have no position information at all, and thus would be totally unconnected to any sense of place within the Universe, totally harring all throughout. And if those maximal-information momenta were equal, indeed, Pauli would exclude that.

Answer (score 0):

The spatial part of the wave function is part of the state.

Two electrons in the same isolated atom have the same spatial part of their state, hence can be subject to the exclusion principle. Two in well-separated atoms don’t have the same spatial wave function, hence can’t be in the same state, hence are not subject to the exclusion principle.

It can get complicated with overlapping cases, I.e. in chemical bonds, and when the electrons have a historical connection leading to entanglement.  But in the simple cases in the question, separated electrons have different spatial parts to their state, hence are not in the same state.